Gitlab CI does not run any job when merge request is created
my gitlab CI does not run any job when merge request is opened.
I tried using my old project's CI which used to work on MR but dosen't work now, how is this possible? Is there some issue with Gitlab?
here is my .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - danger

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

image: gradle:8.4.0-jdk17-jammy

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - .gradle
    - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - gradle test

danger:
  stage: danger
  image: node:18
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - npm install
    - npx danger ci

